# Form validation error in django using celery in background

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, celery, celery-task

I have a django app in which i have the below form

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
  address = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 20}))
  city = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 15}))
  state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=settings.SITE_STATE_CHOICES)
  zipcode = USZipCodeField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10}))
```

My view was something like below

```
def process_address(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddressForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            ..........
            ..........
            ..........
```

when i processed the above view the request.GET dictionary was `{'city': 'Monroeville', 'state': 'PA', 'zipcode': '15146', 'address': '700 Beatty Rd #355'}`

Here when i process the view normally from frontend on the page, the form is validating and returning `True`, but when i processed the same view with `celery`(like i used `delay` method provided by celery) the form was not validating and returning `False`.

So i am really confused on why django can't able to validate the Form when we process it from celery in background, all i changed was just running the process like `process_address.delay(request)`.

Is there anything that we need to set for celery options to make the form validating i don't think so, can any one point me a way on how to debug in celery for why the form is not validating in background even though the input dictionary was same?

Comment: What is process_address doing? You don't show it in your original code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Actually this view is used for processing a csv file that contains addresses.

Comment: I don't understand what it has to do with validating the form. You need to show how you're doing that - you've snipped too much in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the request object to a celery task since it does not accept objects as arguments. Pass the required value from request that you are using within the task as the argument. That should work